# Changing the button color after it is clicked

Tags: sass

I would like to change the background colour of "After" to blue upon clicking, but no matter what it just doesn't show. I'm not sure what is wrong here in SCSS. Would really appreciate any advice!

Here's the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u1h9fe6v/

```
.grid-list {
  --color: #f6f8ff;
  --background: #2b3044;
  --background-hover: green;
  --background-active: blue;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 8px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: var(--b, var(--background));
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearence: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(var(--scale, 1)) translateZ(0);
}
.grid-list:active {
  --scale: 0.95;
  --background-active: blue;
}
.grid-list:hover {
  --b: var(--background-hover);
}
```

Comment: But you don't use `--background-active` anywhere?

Comment: Hello! I added them everywhere (on the JS Fiddle too) but it doesn't change anything ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can set the background color in the
".grid-list.animation.active {" style. Like this ...

```
.grid-list.animation.active {
  --span-name: text-active;
  --dots-name: move;
  --lines-name: scale;
  --lines-duration: 0.15s;
  --lines-delay: 0.3s;
  background: blue;
}
```